# Fetching news articles from plain html website

Tags: gnus

**Problem setting:** my school has an [official website](https://yjwb.seiee.sjtu.edu.cn/yjwb/list/2857-1-20.htm#) with a news section where news articles get posted every now and then. The problem with this site is that the search function is somewhat broken and I have to browse through all the news articles manually in order to find the content of interest.

I have learned that *gnus* is a wonderful tool for browsing news so I wonder is there any built-in functionality that can extract news title and links from the webpage? I searched the website but found no source of structured sources like RSS. My current idea of automation is to write a small script to fetch and parse the html file to generate local xml which would be fed to gnus. Does anyone has better/less cumbersome ideas?

Comment: I think it's possible to avoid the intermediate XML file if you do something similar to what this guy did to read Twitter with gnus.  https://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2020/08/31/you-still-cant-read-twitter-with-gnus/

Comment: Of course, "this guy" is the guy who wrote Gnus, so he has a leg up on the rest of us...

Comment: thanks mate, I will check that out.